# Flow free like game Unity3d (line drawing)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a game like Flow Free for android.
so, I'm new in unity and I can't figure out how to implement line drawing.
I've tried to use Linerenderers but it seems to be very slow for rendering in old generation devices, also it is too hard to round the corners or draw an arc in linerenderer.
maybe there are any other solutions that would help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlikely, Unity isn't big on the whole idea of lines. There is `Debug.DrawLine(Vector3 start, Vector3 end)`, however it will of course only work whilst the game is built in development mode or when run in the editor. LineRenderers are very much your only choice without learning OpenGL, which is kind of like attacking an ant with a sledgehammer to be honest.